# Shifting magnetic field axis

Tags: magnetic-fields, vector-fields

Considering the image below, I have magnetometer readings while my magnetometer is oriented along x' and y'. Can I convert these readings to get the equivalent reading if my magnetometer was oriented along x and y.

$\theta$ is known and the field I am trying to measure is the geo-static field in a closed environment.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, to find the components of the magnetic field $B$ in the new coordinate system, you simply have to apply a rotation matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix} B'_x \\ B'_y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} B_x \\ B_y \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now if I have a z-field as well which always goes into the plane(doesn't change its orientation with the above-specified rotation), will it be included in the rotation calculation for the x and y-axis.

Comment: @SaharshBansal The $z$ component is unaffected and remains the same, since this rotation is only in the $x$-$y$ plane.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I was wondering more along the lines if the x and y rotations would have some effect because of the z component.  Something like:
[$B_x'$  $B_y'$  $B_z'$]= [$\cos{\theta}$  $\sin{\theta}$  $factor_1$;  -$\sin{\theta}$ 
 $cos{\theta}$  $factor_2$; 0  0  1] $\times$ [$B_x$   $B_y$   $B_z$]
Is factor1 and factor2 some value or is it 0.

Comment: @SaharshBansal The axes are orthogonal, so the $z$ component is independent, therefore the factors are zero.

Comment: Thank you. This has been most helpful

Comment: I tried using the mentioned rotation matrix and got the following [results](https://ibb.co/2501kkt) for the x field.  Similar results for the y field as well. Not sure if I have missed on something.

Comment: @SaharshBansal I am unable to comment on this as you have not provided enough information on what you are trying to do. In addition, I do not see what the results are supposed to mean.

Comment: As per the image the sectioned labeled "correct orientation" shows the field along the x-y coordinate system. The area labeled as "rotated anti-clock" shows the field measured after rotating the coordinate system in a anti-clockwise direction and similarl for the region labeled "rotated clock". The rotated measurements shown in the graph are what were calculated after scaling the data read from the magnetometer with the rotation matrix. From what I understand the graph should be a relatively straight line given that I am rotatin the axis using the matrix, but it doesnt turn out so practically.

Comment: The provided results are only for the calculated x field but a similar trend holds for the y field as well. 
P.S.: the y axis readings are in T(tesla units) and the x axis shows the time.

Comment: @SaharshBansal If the results you posted is only for the $x$-component, then it is correct. The components are supposed to change. The invariant quantity is the magnitude ${B_x}^2 + {B_y}^2$.

Comment: Maybe Im getting this wrong but after applying the rotation matrix to the values obtained at x', shouldn't the individual axis values resemble what they would be at x.
P.S. All the values in the graph are for the x field in the x-y orientation. The values in the anti-clock and clock sectors are what were obtained for x and y after x' and y' were multiplied with the rotation matrix

Comment: "*after applying the rotation matrix to the values obtained at x', shouldn't the individual axis values resemble what they would be at x*" **No. Then what is the point of applying the matrix in the first place?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A magnetic field is a vector field, so you can rotate the coordinate system as you want. You'll have to incorporate the error in the angle measurement into the error analysis of the field measurement.

Even if you can't move the probe permanently, you might be able to temporarily move the probe around the magnet or the magnet around the probe to see that the readings change as you would expect from a simple rotation.